# Woocommerce Cart not Clearing on Successful Payment

Tags: php, function, woocommerce

I've got a problem with WooCommerce not clearing the cart after being re-directed from the payment gateway - Payfast. The Items still stays in the Cart until the page gets refreshed.

I've implemented this code into my child theme's functions.php to a force cart clear on pages with the slug thank-you, checkout and order-received.

```
//Force Clear Cart
add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
global $woocommerce;

if ( is_page( array( 'thank-you', 'checkout', 'order-received' ) ) && isset( $_GET['empty-cart'] ) ) { 
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart(); 
}
} 

add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'order_received_empty_cart_action', 10, 
1 );
function order_received_empty_cart_action( $order_id ){
WC()->cart->empty_cart();
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work as indented.

Comment: Try executing the same functions on a simple page when you have something in the cart : do they work then ?

Answer (score 3):

The function `order_received_empty_cart_action()` usually runs lower on down the page,  after the cart menu item has already loaded.  So you only see the clearing of the cart on the next page load.

Then the `woocommerce_clear_cart_url()` is running on the `init` action,   usually the WP_Query for the page has not run yet,  so `is_page()` will return false, as it doesnt know what page it is yet. If you run that on `wp_head()` it works well.

Here is a combined solution

```html
<?php
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_clear_cart' );
function my_clear_cart() {
 if ( is_page( array( 'thank-you', 'order-received' ) ) && isset( $_GET['order-received'] ) ) {
  WC()->cart->empty_cart();
 }
}
```